# Why is the relation $Z_N = (Z_1^N)/ N!$ applicable only when $Z_1$ is much larger than $N$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, partition-function

If the N particles are
distinguishable, then we can write the N-particle partition function ZN
as
$Z_N = (Z1^N).$
For indistinguishable particles:
$ZN =(Z1^N)/N!$
This result has assumed that it is possible to ignore those states in
which two or more particles occupy the same energy level. When is this
approximation possible? We will have only one particle occupying any
given state if the system is in a regime when the number of available
states is much larger than the number of particles. So for the ideal gas,
we require that the number of thermally accessible energy levels must
be much larger than the number of molecules in the gas. **This occurs
when N, the number of particles, is much less than the number of states**.

I did not get this point.

Comment: You have to clarify your setting. Obviously your result doesn't hold for an interacting theory. Also are you dealing with quantum or classical mechanics? If the former, bosons fermions or distinguishable?

Comment: It's pure combinatorics. $\frac{Z1^N}{N!}$ is an approximate formula for exact expression $\frac{(Z1+N-1)!}{{N!}{(Z1-1)!}}$ when $Z1>>N$

Comment: It is in quantum statistics and it refers to bosons and fermions.

Comment: No, only to bosons that is, to indistinguishable particles without limiting the number in one microstate (unlike fermions, for them $\frac{Z1!}{{N!}{(Z1-N)!}}$ and it also also goes into $\frac{Z1^N}{N!}$ as $Z1>>N$